# Why is the next Line of Code Not Executing C#?

Tags: c#

I am new to C#. The next line of code is not executing in my small program and I am unable to figure out why.

Main method

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Loan Approval Software"); 

    Customer inputCustomer = new Customer(); 
    inputCustomer.Name = Console.ReadLine(); 

    Console.WriteLine($"Hello {inputCustomer.Name}"); 
}
```

Class

```
public class Customer
{
    // property
    public string? Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What is your error?

Comment: What is the `...next line of code` that you think is the issue?

Comment: Please always provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem. If you're talking about a "next" then there must be a "current", so you need to tell us what they are. In this case, we can make an educated guess where the issue might and thus what it might be. If we guess wrong, we've wasted our time and yours. We shouldn't have to guess or assume anything that you already know, because you should tell us.

Comment: Please consider Removing this question it doesn't have any problem and code run find , and there is no clarification about the problem as John said

Answer (score 1):

I just ran your code and it worked fine.

Please note this line: `inputCustomer.Name = Console.ReadLine();`

Will halt code execution until you enter in a name to the CLI.

You can see below it worked just fine. If you are getting some kind of other error or have questions about a specific line feel free to comment, but so far code is running as it should.

[image]

EDIT FOR DEMO

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    while(true)
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Loan Approval Software"); 

       Customer inputCustomer = new Customer(); 
       inputCustomer.Name = Console.ReadLine(); 

       Console.WriteLine($"Hello {inputCustomer.Name}"); 
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry for the terrible question. Basically when I run this I enter a name and nothing happens after that. The console.writeline message doesn't appear. I assume it must be an issue with the software.

Comment: Ahh I see now. That is because your program is actually completing execution. Look at my answer above. I put your code in a while loop so you can see what I am talking about.  The code above will print out the lines you are expecting so you can see that after the last console.writeline your program terminates. This should answer your question now.